# in scala the variables called res that are returned by the REPL are val (constant) or var (mutable)?

Tags: scala

In scala shell, are the res variables `val` or `var`?

thanks.

Comment: Maybe there was a reason SO didn't let you post. I did not understand the question. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: It seems that the title of this question is copied directly from page 13 of [Cay Horstmann's "Scala for the Impatient"](http://logic.cse.unt.edu/tarau/teaching/scala_docs/scala-for-the-impatient.pdf).

Comment: "SO for the quite terrifically impatient."

Comment: Voted down because the author could have found out the answer in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

res in scala shell are ***val.***

you can verify this by trying to reassign a value to res.

> e.g. - scala> List(1) 
> res1: List[Int] = List(1)
>
> scala> res1=List(2) 
> console>:8: error: reassignment to val
>          res1=List(2)

Answer (score 2):

Showing that the `res` variable (`varName`) is only used in `val res = expr`:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/repl/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/IMain.scala#L495

(The variant is that `x ; y` is rewritten to `x ; val res = y` or similar.)